# Which Oauth2 grant type for server-to-server integration

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

We have a proxy layer that delivers messages from a channel (think facebook messenger/twitter/sms/etc) to a 3rd party omni-channel contact centre platform.

The platform API's are secured using OAuth2's authorization code grant type. We create an 'application' within the platform space and use the provided client ID and secret to set up a basic web page with a bit of Javascript to receive the access code when the auth provider redirects to this page.

Using this code, we're able to generate auth tokens which are fed into our proxy layer.

In turn, our proxy creates access tokens for each messaging user that it needs to interact with the platform as. This works fine in the back-end layer.

My problem is that 
1) the method of generating the initial code is a complete hack
2) our proxy is a pure back-end service that is not able to interact with a user-agent i.e.: a web browser; and therefore is unable to receive the code from the browser via a redirect from the OAuth provider.

I've spent some time reading through the OAuth2 spec and some blog posts too and from what I can tell, client_credentials is the correct grant type for this form of integration.

However, the platform's dev team are insistent that auth code will work for us.

I'm open to being wrong - but where I'm stuck is on how we're meant to create the initial tokens for the proxy layer given that the proxy layer is a pure back-end service.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Client credentials is definitely correct. Authorization code flow should only be used for an end user UI.

But it may be that you are interfacing with a non standard architecture that doesn't support the correct option - or politically you cannot get the buy in.

I would aim to win over the platform dev team.- buy them a beer etc

Worst case scenario you can register a pseudo user and write some HttpClient based back end code to do the Auth code flow by reading 302 location headers etc and gettimg a code then token. This will automate the login but is very hacky as you say.

I.would try my hardest to avoid it though - and make my stakeholders aware that I'm using the only option available and it could have future reliability problems

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions about using client credentials. 

I'd happily attempt to bribe them with sparkly beverages; but the cost of the flight to the next continent might just outweigh the benefits for me.

Looks like I'll take the hack hit for now and attempt to win their favour for the 'correct' implementation.